# Not able to import urllib for Python 3 although it seems to be installed

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib

I'm trying to import the modules:

```
import urllib.request, urllib.error, urllib.parse
```

And get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bla.py", line 11, in <module>
    import urllib.request, urllib.error, urllib.parse
ImportError: No module named request
```

I found the modules installed in the directory:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/urllib
```

In this directory, there are the files: `request.py`, `error.py`, `parse.py`. 
So I don't get why the import doesn't work. I'm executing with Python 3.5.

Comment: You are probably running a different Python than the one in that directory. Since these libraries are not showing as iinstalled, it si likelly you are running some Python 2.x, not the Python 3.5 you are expecting.

Comment: Please post the results of `which python`and `python --version`, just to be sure

Comment: Simple test: try to run a program that contains `print "Hello World!"`, if it works you are running python2 and not python3.5

Comment: >>> which python
/usr/bin/python
>>> python --version
Python 2.7.10
>>> python3 --version
Python 3.5.2

Interpreter of project is Python 3, verified with hello world test..